# vb.net: How can I access to models in main project from BLL?

Tags: vb.net

I have a BLL (Bussiness Logic Layer) project which  is added in the main project with some structure (View-Controller-Model).

Do I have some way to accesss them from BLL?

Comment: Why don't you simply define your models in your BLL project, too? Or create a third project that is referenced by both.

Comment: If "BLL" project references "Models", then add a reference of models to BLL

Comment: not interested in that because it is like MVC, if you are working in MVC 4 of Microsoft you know we can not separete the models of the system for this reason I asked.

Comment: Anyway I will pass the entity directly and it solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved at the moment using reflection and passing the model to the entity, which I will work